# UserManager.CreateAsync hangs on execution from Unit Test but not Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity

I'm really baffled right now. So I've been working on a Web API and unit testing the project as I'm going and just made a change with a lot of controllers recently but completely left the AccountController untouched. In my AccountController I have the function Register() which has been working great for the past 2 months everytime I test. Now all of a sudden though when I enter Register and call,

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

My program hangs and won't come back. I tested some things out and this only happens when called from my unit test (Which also hasn't changed) and when I call Register from Postman with the exact same JSON it works just fine.

**Register API Function**

```
// POST api/Account
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, Active = true, CreationDate = DateTime.Now };

    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return GetErrorResult(result);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

**Test Function**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Register_Pass()
{
    // Arrange & Act
    var db = new WizardSwearsDB();

    new DBCleanup().RemoveRegisteredUser(userName);
    string apiCall = "";
    new
    {
        UserName = userName,
        Email = email,
        Password = password,
        ConfirmPassword = password
    }.Post(baseUrl + apiCall);

    var user = (from u in db.AspNetUsers
                where u.UserName == userName
                select u).FirstOrDefault();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(user);
    Assert.AreEqual(userName, user.UserName);
}
```

**JSON Post Functionality**

```
public static void Post(this object obj, string url, string securityToken = null)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    obj.Request<string>(url, postJsonRequestBuilder, null, securityToken);
}

private static Func<string, object, string, WebRequest> postJsonRequestBuilder = (url, o, st) => jsonRequestBuilder(url, o, "POST", st);

private static Func<string, object, string, string, WebRequest> jsonRequestBuilder = delegate(string url, object obj, string method, string securityToken)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(securityToken)) request.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", securityToken));
    request.Method = method;
    if (obj != null)
    {
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        var payload = encoding.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
        request.ContentLength = payload.Length;
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(payload, 0, payload.Length);
        }
    }
    return request;
};
```

**Remove Registered User Function and Remove Employee Function**

```
public void RemoveRegisteredUser(string userName)
{
    // Open up a connection to the database
    var db = new WizardSwearsDB();

    // Get the user from the ASPNetUsers table
    var dbUserASP = (from b in db.AspNetUsers
                    where b.UserName == userName
                    select b).FirstOrDefault();


    // Remove the user from both tables and save changes
    if (dbUserASP != null)
    {
        db.AspNetUsers.Remove(dbUserASP);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    RemoveEmployee(userName);
}

public void RemoveEmployee(string userName)
{
    // Open up a connection to the database
    var db = new WizardSwearsDB();

    // Get the user from the ASPNetUsers table
    var employee = (from b in db.Employees
                    where b.UserName == userName
                    select b).FirstOrDefault();

    // Remove the user from both tables and save changes
    if (employee != null)
    {
        db.Employees.Remove(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

So none of these functions have changed at all, and my guess is it has to do something with await, but I just can't figure out why it is behaving this way.

Comment: Apologies for asking the obvious, but what happens when you step through the unit test? You should be able to figure out where it's hanging pretty quickly. Meaning both client and server in debug mode.

Comment: I've stepped through the whole unit test and nothing hangs there, but it hangs on the server side on the call,

IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved the problem. Did a full restart of my computer and Visual Studio and voila. On a side note, anyone familiar with why this fixed the issue? Maybe just a Visual Studio bug?

Comment: Usually hangs on async code are because you are not using async all the way, mixing a `Task<T>.Result` in with `await` in the call stack. But that would not be fixed by a restart of VS so maybe you did experience an bug in VS?

Comment: I've got the same problem, but even a restart didn't help so far :/
In my case I can even see the hang in debugging when I run all Tests in Debugging. I can step onto CreateAsync and have it hang on me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue arising from trying to create a user with an existing username - no error, just nothing, blank.